# Wordpress DATABASE Update Manually?

Tags: database, upgrade, ssl, automatic-updates

I have a multisite WP and I'm now trying to update my WP to latest version. In the WP Administration Panel, there is a Network Update page at:

- Updates > Available Updates *(.../wp-admin/network/update-core.php)*

There i was able to do press the `[Update Now]` button. Then it updated the CODE BASE. So far ok.

Then after that i need to upgrade the **DATABASE** again for network, as shown in:

- Updates > Update Network *(.../wp-admin/network/upgrade.php)*

Then it critically FAILED. It is showing:

```
Warning! Problem updating http://www.example.com/site1. Your server may not be able to connect to sites running on it. 
Error message: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
```

In this post, i won't be asking for "how to solve this" particular problem. *(I'm asking "why/how" in [another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115279/wordpress-database-upgrade-error))*

Now, alternatively, my another question would be:

- HOW TO **UPGRADE THE WP DATABASE "MANUALLY"** ? *(As like we can upgrade the CODEBASE manually, [shown here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress))*

Answer (score 4):

Visit `/wp-admin/upgrade.php` on each site to manually upgrade the database e.g.

`http://www.example.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php`

This happens if you have a site on the WordPress network that doesn't resolve or if you have spoofed DNS locally but not on the server - your computer knows that www.example.com points at 127.0.0.1 but your local server is still resolving www.example.com to its actual address when PHP does its CURL call.

Answer (score 3):

From quick look at the code upgrade motions are performed by [`wp_upgrade()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.6/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L293) function. I imagine calling it in some way would get it done, but postponing it until normal upgrade process is fixed is probably more efficient.

In recent versions WP rarely does major changes to DB and it's reasonable expectation for it to not need database upgrade *urgently* after files changed at least.